# How does the MessageListener running in JMS? Can it load messages in the queue in real time?

Tags: java, jms

I want to load the JMS messages in a queue in real time, if is a consumer.setMessageListener(myListener) viable and how it works?

I'm not sure how a listener working. I wrote a listener like below.

```
public class JmsMessageListenerExample {
public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, Exception {
    BrokerService broker = BrokerFactory.createBroker(new URI(
            "broker:(tcp://localhost:61616)"));
    broker.start();
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        // Producer
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(
                "tcp://localhost:61616");
        connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        Session session = connection.createSession(false,
                Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        Queue queue = session.createQueue("customerQueue");
        String payload = "Important Task";
        Message msg = session.createTextMessage(payload);
        MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);
        System.out.println("Sending text '" + payload + "'");
        producer.send(msg);

        // Consumer
        MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);
        consumer.setMessageListener(new ConsumerMessageListener("Consumer"));
        connection.start();
    } finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.close();
        }
        broker.stop();
    }
}
```

After I run the JmsMessageListenerExample, it completed quickly and I didn't received any messages. If a listener should keep on running until I stop it?

Comment: Hi Goa, connection.start() will just start the connection but then your program exits. You probably want to wait for messages first. Maybe initially using: while(true) { Thread.sleep(1000); } just after connection.start() ? (note: other forms of wait() are better, but for this test this is easiest).

Answer (score 3):

When you set a JMS message listener it will receive messages asynchronously in its own thread (invoked by the JMS implementation). In your case you need to prevent `main` from exiting and stopping your application because when that happens the `MessageListener` will be terminated.

Also, when you say "load the JMS messages in a queue in real time" I assume you mean "consume JMS messages from a queue as soon as possible when queue receives them." If that's the case then a JMS message listener is the right approach.